# Have pager (less) re-run git log upon keypress

Tags: git, less

Sometimes I find it handy to have the git commit graph (given by `git log`) displayed side-by-side to the terminal pane I'm working in.

`git log` is run with the `less` pager by default and only shows the state of the branches at the time of invocation. Is there a way to have `less` re-read the output of `git log` upon keypress to display the current state?

My workaround right now is to quit the pager and invoke `git log` again, but that's cumbersome.

I've seen that there's <kbd>r</kbd> or <kbd>STRG+r</kbd> or <kbd>STRG+L</kbd> to repaint the screen in less but that's not querying git a second time.

There are people who use `watch` in combination with `git log` to have an ever updating history but that doesn't work with a pager and I like to keep the pager functionality.

Comment: Could you periodically write the output of `git log` to a file and `less +F` on the file?

Comment: That would be an option, yes.